# My deep learning model is not training. How do I make it train?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm fairly new to Keras, please excuse me if I made a fundamental error. So, my model has 3 Convolutional (2D) layers and 4 Dense Layers, interspersed with Dropout Layers. I am trying to train a **Regression** Model using images.

X_train.shape = (5164, 160, 320, 3)

y_train.shape = (5164)

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Activation, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.losses import Huber
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.schedules import ExponentialDecay

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(160, 320, 3), filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="valid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, padding="valid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, padding="valid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(1))

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="./ckpts/model.ckpt", monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)
stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.0003, patience = 10)

lr_schedule = ExponentialDecay(initial_learning_rate=0.1, decay_steps=10000, decay_rate=0.9)
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
loss = Huber(delta=0.5, reduction="auto", name="huber_loss")

model.compile(loss = loss, optimizer = optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split = 0.2, shuffle = True, epochs = 100, 
          callbacks=[checkpoint, stopper])

model.save('model.h5')
```

When I try to run this model, the training loss decreases as expected, the validation loss hovers around the same region, and the validation accuracy stays **exactly** the same. I'm not asking for inputs to improve my model (I'll do that on my own), but I need help to get the model unstuck. I want to see the validation accuracy change, even in the third decimal place, decrease or increase doesn't matter. How can I get my model unstuck?

Here's an image of what happens when I try to train the model:
[image]

Any solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue in this code was the **metric**. Accuracy, being a classification metric doesn't work on Regression models. Decreasing initial learning rate to 0.0001 helped as well.

A slightly different implementation got a more conclusive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64998875/transfer-learning-model-is-giving-unchanged-loss-results-is-it-not-training)

Comment: Adam even without learning_rate can be adaptive itself in order gradient could converge properly

Answer (score 0):

Your model is underfitting. It is caused due to insufficient dense layers and neurons. There are many ways to prevent to the underfitting such as,

1. Increasing the number of Convolutional and Dense layers.
2. Increasing the number of neurons in the existing layers.
3. Reduce the Dropout Rate.
4. Try reducing the dimensions of the input image before giving input to the input layers.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. However, I can't add more convolutions because after these three layers, the output is (2,8,1024), so adding any more layers of conv, fails due to dimentionality. I've reduced the dropout rate, removed some of the dropout layers, but it doesn't work. I've increased Dense layer depth, but it's still the same. The validation accuracy is still at a fixed 0.5516, same as before, even though validation loss keeps decreasing.

Comment: I don't see a behaviour here that I would interpret as underfitting. It seems to me the training is just very unstable and doesn't converge properly. Looking at your initial learning rate, I'd assume it's too high. You can also debug the predictions in detail, figuring out if the model makes only 0 predictions for exmaple.

Comment: Yeah, Always start first with lower learning rate and add dense layers instead of increasing the number of neurons in the existing layer.