# My model's Validation Accuracy is stuck! How do I fix it? [Tensorflow/Keras]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a **Regression** model for a series of images on my Local PC running on an Nvidia RTX 2070 Super.

Input image Shape: (96,160,3), 16072 Samples (12857 for training, 3215 for validation)

However, the training is not taking place. I tried using a custom model, as mentioned in this
[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944914/my-deep-learning-model-is-not-training-how-do-i-make-it-train).

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(96, 320, 3), filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="valid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, padding="valid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, padding="valid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2048))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(1))

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="./ckpts/model.ckpt", monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)
stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.0003, patience = 10)

lr_schedule = ExponentialDecay(initial_learning_rate=0.1, decay_steps=10000, decay_rate=0.9)
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
loss = Huber(delta=0.5, reduction="auto", name="huber_loss")
model.compile(loss = loss, optimizer = optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split = 0.2, shuffle = True, epochs = 100, 
          callbacks=[checkpoint, stopper])
```

The training went on for 10 epochs before automatically terminating after exhausting patience of Early Stopping Algorithm. Essentially, the model did not train. The validation accuracy was stuck at 0.5353.
[image: Custom Model Training]

Then, suspecting something may be wrong with my model itself, I tried Transfer Learning, importing pre-trained **Inception V3** with Imagenet weights, and tried training with frozen weights (only training the last two layers with the pre-trained weights frozen).

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Activation, MaxPooling2D, 
      Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3, preprocess_input
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.losses import Huber
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.schedules import ExponentialDecay

X_train = preprocess_input(X_train)
inception = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(299,299,3))
inception.trainable = False

driving_input = Input(shape=(96,320,3))
resized_input = Lambda(lambda image: tf.image.resize(image,(299,299)))(driving_input)
inp = inception(resized_input)

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(inp)
x = Dense(512, activation = 'relu')(x)
result = Dense(1, activation = 'relu')(x)


model = Model(inputs = driving_input, outputs = result)
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mse', metrics = ['accuracy'])

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="./ckpts/model.ckpt", monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)
stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.0003, patience = 10)

batch_size = 32
epochs = 100

model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.2, epochs=epochs, 
          batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, callbacks=[checkpoint, stopper])
```

The result I got did not solve my issue.
[image: InceptionV3 Frozen]

I finally also tried unfreezing the weights and retraining the entire InceptionV3 Network, initialized with the Imagenet pre-trained weights.

```
inception.trainable = True
```

This also did not produce any change in my model's performance. The validation accuracy is still very much stuck at the same place.

[image]

I don't understand why my model is not training. Please help me solve this issue. Do note that I do not expect help with improving my model in general, I can do that myself, but what I can't do is getting the model unstuck. Unless that happens, I can't proceed with any fine tuning or optimization. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I think your issue is with your loss function. I dont know what kind of training you are trying to do but try changing the loss function. Also it is better to have your number of neurons per layer decrese gradually instead of going from 128(minus dropout) to 1. Add some more layers here and if you are restricted by vram, then reduce 128 to something lesser but add some more layers. Also try out only simple Adam with lr decay or maybe some other optimiser.

Comment: Is your data a public dataset? and can you share it?

Comment: @NiteyaShah I just trained it on simple Adam with MSE loss with two more Dense layers between 128 and 1, with 54 and 16 neurons respectively. The validation accuracy remains stuck. Outcome was very similar to the first output image, in the post.

Comment: @Niki It's a simulation dataset. Let me upload it for you to have a look https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5vtobw4m8km49rt/AAB08NjkyPj8dtP9_RqSWzFka?dl=0

Comment: In my first impression, The data is very the same. also, your regression task may be stuck in a minimum local error. If your doubt is about the model I think changing the optimizer to SGD and increase the learning rate you may see the loss is changing. I think you need to do more for preprocessing and generating better features for detection (if you don't want to let the DeepNets work everything for you.)

Comment: @Niki So here's what I did for preprocessing:
- Cropped all these images to exclude the sky, keeping till the horizon line, where the road ends.
- Augemented the data to get more for training. Flipped all these images horizontally and multiplied all the regression labels with -1. This means when the image gets flipped, the steering angle also turns to negative(if the unflipped image was to turn left, the flipped image would have to turn right), thereby producing sensible augmented data.
I tried with Adam, RMSprop. They didn't work. I tried with MSE loss, Huber Loss, they didn't work either.

Comment: Just tried SGD. Same thing. I don't even think its about the model anymore. I've tried Inception V3 and NASNet, both huge networks. They also don't train for some reason. You think it's something to do with generators? Do I have to use a generator? I did that for classfiication tasks when I used categorical_crossentropy, but for regression, do I somehow have to implement that as well?

Comment: I think you are completely ignoring that accuracy is a classification metric, and you are doing regression, so using this metric in this context makes no sense.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy you are right but that still doesnt explain why the loss isn't dropping. As said on keras documentation, `Metric functions are similar to loss functions, except that the results from evaluating a metric are not used when training the model. `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Dr. Snoopy for pointing out the fundamental flaw that accuracy is a classification metric. I switched to Validation Loss using the following modified code:

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="./ckpts/model.h5", monitor='val_loss', 
                             save_best_only=True)
stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.0003, patience = 10)

lr_schedule = ExponentialDecay(initial_learning_rate=0.1, decay_steps=10000, 
                                decay_rate=0.9)
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
loss = Huber(delta=0.5, reduction="auto", name="huber_loss")
model.compile(loss = loss, optimizer = optimizer)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split = 0.2, shuffle = True, epochs = 100, 
          callbacks=[checkpoint, stopper])

model.load_weights('./ckpts/model.h5')
model.save('model.h5')
```

The result was an unstuck model:
[image]