# Transfer learning: model is giving unchanged loss results. Is it not training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I'm trying to train a **Regression** Model on Inception V3. Inputs are images of size (96,320,3). There are a total of 16k+ images out of which 12k+ are for training and the rest for validation. I have frozen all layers in Inception, but unfreezing them does not help either (already tried). I've replaced the top of the pre-trained model with a few layers as indicated in the code below.

```
X_train = preprocess_input(X_train)
inception = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(299,299,3))
inception.trainable = False
print(inception.summary())

driving_input = Input(shape=(96,320,3))
resized_input = Lambda(lambda image: tf.image.resize(image,(299,299)))(driving_input)
inp = inception(resized_input)

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(inp)

x = Dense(512, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dense(256, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
result = Dense(1, activation = 'relu')(x)

lr_schedule = ExponentialDecay(initial_learning_rate=0.1, decay_steps=100000, decay_rate=0.95)
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
loss = Huber(delta=0.5, reduction="auto", name="huber_loss")
model = Model(inputs = driving_input, outputs = result)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss)

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="./ckpts/model.h5", monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)
stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.0003, patience = 10)

batch_size = 32
epochs = 100

model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.2, epochs=epochs, 
          batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, callbacks=[checkpoint, stopper])
```

This results in this:
[image]

Why is my model not training, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Do note that this behavior is also observable with the much larger NASNet(84M parameters as compared to InceptionV3's 22M parameters), again trained with frozen weights, excluded top and few added Dense Layers.

Comment: No exact solution can be given to your problem, as a number of factors are responsible in a scenario where the loss doesn't decrease. You may try *unfreezing* some top layers in InceptionV3/NASNet i.e by setting `trainable=True`. This would allow the pre-trained model to generalize better on the new data provided to it.

Comment: Why your last layer activation is `relu` instead of `linear`? Also, your `lr` is too high.

Comment: I wonder why the question is closed by an opinion-based tag where it's not.

Comment: Same. This is not an opinion-based post. I was trying to get the model unstuck, and the correct hint was to change from relu to linear in the last layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your problem is a regression problem, the activation of the last layer should be `linear` instead of `relu`. And also the learning rate is too high, you should consider to lower it according to your overall set up. Here I'm showing a code sample with MNIST.

```py
# data 
(xtrain, train_target), (xtest, test_target) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
# train_x, MNIST is gray scale, so in order to use it in pretrained weights , extending it to 3 axix
x_train = np.expand_dims(xtrain, axis=-1)
x_train = np.repeat(x_train, 3, axis=-1)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
# prepare the label for regression model 
ytrain4 = tf.square(tf.cast(train_target, tf.float32))

# base model 
inception = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(75,75,3))
inception.trainable = False

# inputs layer
driving_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28,28,3))
resized_input = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda image: tf.image.resize(image,(75,75)))(driving_input)
inp = inception(resized_input)

# top model 
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(inp)
x = Dense(512, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dense(256, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
result = Dense(1, activation = 'linear')(x)

# hyper-param
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(initial_learning_rate=0.0001, 
                                                             decay_steps=100000, decay_rate=0.95)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
loss = tf.keras.losses.Huber(delta=0.5, reduction="auto", name="huber_loss")

# build models
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = driving_input, outputs = result)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss)

# callbacks
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath="./ckpts/model.h5", monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)
stopper = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.0003, patience = 10)

batch_size = 32
epochs = 10

# fit 
model.fit(x=x_train, y=ytrain4, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.2, epochs=epochs, 
          batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, callbacks=[checkpoint, stopper])
```

**Output**

```
1500/1500 [==============================] - 27s 18ms/step - loss: 5.2239 - val_loss: 3.6060
Epoch 2/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 26s 17ms/step - loss: 3.5634 - val_loss: 2.9022
Epoch 3/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 26s 17ms/step - loss: 3.0629 - val_loss: 2.5063
Epoch 4/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 26s 17ms/step - loss: 2.7615 - val_loss: 2.3764
Epoch 5/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 26s 17ms/step - loss: 2.5371 - val_loss: 2.1303
Epoch 6/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 26s 17ms/step - loss: 2.3848 - val_loss: 2.1373
Epoch 7/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 26s 17ms/step - loss: 2.2653 - val_loss: 1.9039
Epoch 8/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 26s 17ms/step - loss: 2.1581 - val_loss: 1.9087
Epoch 9/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 26s 17ms/step - loss: 2.0518 - val_loss: 1.7193
Epoch 10/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 26s 17ms/step - loss: 1.9699 - val_loss: 1.8837
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out. Changing from 'relu' to 'linear' was the main issue. Thank you for suggesting a good lr value as well. I am fairly new to this.

Comment: I was banned from asking questions in the forum after this question. I have no idea why. I've tried to ask relevant questions only, recently.

Comment: That sounds unfair. Please contact the moderator or you may get some mail regarding this.